# Como ativar o Migrations usando o Entity Framework Core = Windows Forms C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Estou testando o EF Core em um projeto Windows forms seguindo o padrão DDD. Na camada de repositório eu criei meu contexto e em meu domínio já tenho as classes Models definidas. Como faço para ativar o Migrations no EF Core e de maneira que eu não precise ter que criar cada migração manualmente e ficar dando os updates? Queria que o  Migrations ficasse habilitado e eu só desse o update-database...

```html
public class PersistContext : DbContext
    {
        public PersistContext()
        {
        }

        public PersistContext(DbContextOptions<PersistContext> Options)
            :base(Options)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.ForSqlServerUseIdentityColumns();
            modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("SistemaComercial");

            PessoaTipoMap(modelBuilder);
        }

        public DbSet<PessoaTipo> PessoaTipo { get; set; }

        private void PessoaTipoMap(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<PessoaTipo>(pt =>
            {
                pt.ToTable("tblPessoaTipo");

                pt.HasKey(ptk=> ptk.PessoaTipoId);
                pt.Property(ptp => ptp.PessoaTipoId)
                            .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();//Checar se o auto incremento funciona.

                pt.Property(ptp => ptp.Descricao)
                            .HasColumnName("Descricao")
                            .HasColumnType("Varchar")
                            .HasMaxLength(25)
                            .IsRequired();
            });
        }
    }
```

```html
 public class FactoryPersistContext : IDbContextFactory<PersistContext>
    {
        private string ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SistemaComercial"].ConnectionString;

        public PersistContext Create(DbContextFactoryOptions options)
        {
            var constructor = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<PersistContext>();
            constructor.UseSqlServer(ConnectionString);
            return new PersistContext(constructor.Options);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

Essa opção não existe no Entity Framework Core.

Você pode fazer algo parecido fazendo com que a migração seja feita sempre que a aplicação for iniciada, pra fins de desenvolvimento.

Possivelmente se eu fosse usar esta opção ainda faria alguma verificação pra ter certeza que a aplicação está realmente em modo de desenvolvimento, mas como não sei o contexto não vou opinar sobre isso

Coloque este trecho no código de inicialização da aplicação (provavelmente no `Startup.cs`)

```
using (var contexto = new Contexto())
{
    contexto.Database.Migrate();
}
```